# How to convert Canvas space to world space

Tags: unity-game-engine

I basically want to find a way to set `transform.position = recttransform.position;`

I need a function that converts recttransform position to transform position.

Lets say;

```
RectTransform objectA;

Transform objectB;

Canvas canvas;

Start()
{
 //All i want to do is this..
 objectB.transform.position = CanvasToWorld(canvas, objectA);
}


Vector2 CanvasToWorld(Canvas canvas, RectTransform rect)
{
//Do some function and return world position of the recttransform 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found an easy solution. I hope it will be useful for someone. :)

```
RectTransform objectA;
Transform objectB;

    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(objectA.position);
    objectB.position = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(pos);
```

Comment: `ViewportToWorldPoint()` and `WorldToViewportPoint()` are inverses of each other. `objectA` and `objectB` will end up at the same spot here (unless you meant this as a A->B and B->A function pair)

Comment: @Draco18s I thought the same but this is the only way i get it to work. I do not fully understand how this works. For instance, i tried changing objectB's position to "pos" without casting worldtoviewportpoint, that did not work. The idea is to put them in the same position. One of them is RectTransform, setting their position equal to each other does not do the trick.

Comment: I think you are very confused, they all use the same position, but the default canva is crazy big, maybe it moved but you see it tiny, adjust the canvas to World or Camera space and it works with a = operator.

Answer (score 1):

`transform.position` and `rectTransform.position` are in the same space, World Space, because `RectTransform` inherits from `Transform`, `position` is the same property.

`rectTransform.anchoredPosition` is the one that works on Canvas space

The problem probably resides on your canvas configurations, if it is `Overlay` the position will be far off, but on `Camera` or `World` it should be very precise, you can even change `RectTransform` pivots to change the center of the gameObject.

Comment: if you have accessed the RectTransform as a Transform you can just use transform.position